# redis keys not getting deleted after expire time

Tags: redis

keys set with a expire is not getting cleared after expire time. For example, in reds-cli

```
> set hi bye
>expire hi 10
>ttl hi #=> 9
#(after 10 seconds)
>ttl hi #=> 0
>get hi #=> bye
```

redis version is 2.8.4. This is a master node in a sentinel setup with a single slave. Persistence is turned off.   Kindly help me with debugging this issue.

Comment: `ttl key => 0` means the key is still there. What happens when you check it a bit later? Also, what does `pttl hi` show?

Comment: the ttl value remains 0 even now. And pttl value is also 0.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce it and it seems like a very basic scenario. You can check it here and see it doesn't reproduce also http://try.redis.io/ Better try to reinstall your redis

Comment: that is the whole point. It is working fine in my local. But this behavior is only in one of our servers, which is a master node in a sentinel setup with a single slave. Even this node it was fine until recently, just in last couple of days we are seeing this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If there is any data in redis with a large size, there might be problems while slave nodes sync from master nodes, which might lead to the TTL of these data in slave won't sync and so that the data in slave nodes won't get deleted.
You can use scripts to delete specific data in master node and slave nodes will delete those data whose key can't be found in master node.

Answer (score 0):

Update redis.conf file to keep `notify-keyspace-events Ex` and then restart the redis server using `redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis.conf`